# Как подключить в Laravel свой класс?

Tags: php, laravel

Кто-то может объяснить понятным для новичка языков как правильно подключить в Laravel свой класс? Уже голова кипит: сервис-провайдеры, пакеты, фасады и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Здравствуйте. Для аккуратности создадим отдельную папку, где будет сохранятся все наши классы. Папку назовем library (или же как хотите).
[image: наша папка]

Создаем какой-нибудь класс внутри этой папки, например Setting.

Потом в файле composer.json в разделе autoload->classmap добавляем путь нашей папки например "library".

[image: composer.json]

Потом в консоле вызываем команду composer dump-autoload.

И все, наш класс готов к использованиюю.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Путь/До/Класса/myClass;


public function test() {
    $class = new myClass;
}
```

Класс

```
namespace Путь\До\Класса;

class myClass {
    #введите сюда код
}
```